# How to disable and grey out a form button if the textfield is empty?

Tags: forms, javascript

I have a custom module built, and I would like to grey out and disable the submit form button if the textfield is empty.  Can anyone help?

Here is the code for the textfield and the form button:

```
$form['ro-user-details']['nickname'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield', '#width' => 50,
    '#title' => t('Nickname'),
    '#default_value' => $ro_user->nickname,
    '#size' => 50,
    '#maxlength' => 200,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['ro-user-details']['change_nickname'] = array('#type' => 'submit', '#value' => t('Change Nickname'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you will want to do this with some jQuery...And of course there is more than one way to do this, but:

```
$(function(){
      //Set button disabled
      $("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", "disabled");

      //Append a change event listener to your input
      $("input[name='nickname']").change(function(){

            if($(this).val().length > 0) {
              $("input[type='submit']").removeAttr("disabled");  
            }                            
      });

      // You could then trigger the a change event on load just to check
      $("input[name='nickname'").trigger('change');
});
```

That should be the gist of it.  Of course you would want to change your "name" value to whatever your input name is.

Comment: If you want to add custom JS, then you should use [behaviors](http://drupal.org/node/756722) (look towards the bottom) to ensure that the JS is run on all markup (even stuff that gets AJAXed down after the initial page load). Note that a non-JS method would be to use the states API.

Comment: Be aware that the onclick event for the button will still, so if the button has javascript behavior, it will probably trigger anyways.